# compute time difference between rows and conditional group by using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, group-by, lag

I have data like as shown below:

```
+-------+-------+
| index | time  |
+-------+-------+
|     1 | 09.00 |
|     2 | 09.02 |
|     3 | 09.03 |
|     4 | 09.05 |
|     5 | 09.11 |
|     6 | 09.12 |
|     7 | 09.15 |
|     8 | 09.22 |
|     9 | 09.33 |
+-------+-------+
```

If the time difference between rows is <= 5 mins, assign them the same id as shown below. I expect my output to be like as shown below:

```
+-------+-------+
| index | time  |
+-------+-------+
|     1 | 09.00 |
|     1 | 09.02 |
|     1 | 09.03 |
|     1 | 09.05 |
|     2 | 09.11 |
|     2 | 09.12 |
|     2 | 09.15 |
|     3 | 09.22 |
|     4 | 09.33 |
+-------+-------+
```

I was trying something like below

```sql
    select index, (lag_time - time) from (
    select 
        index, 
        time,
        LAG(time,1) OVER (
            ORDER BY time
        ) lag_time) A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_time < time - interval '5 minute') over (order by time) as index
from (select t.*,
             lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f58735a682f44ee687d43fc3ed5ab28) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: There is an error with this query.. `column "t.index" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: @TheGreat . . . I don't understand the error.  This is a window function and doesn't need aggregation.

Comment: Lindoff - You can refer the db here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3c4579e88225e747b63da06674263a8e

Comment: @TheGreat . . . That is not the query in this answer.  You are missing the `over` clause.  I added a fiddle to the answer.